# Problema al crear base de datos SQLite en dispositivos Android con Flutter

Tags: android, base-de-datos, flutter, apk, sqflite

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Flutter que utiliza una base de datos SQLite para almacenar datos localmente. La aplicación funciona perfectamente en Windows, pero al ejecutarla en dispositivos Android, la base de datos no se crea correctamente y no puedo almacenar datos.

He verificado los permisos en el archivo AndroidManifest.xml y ya tengo los permisos WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE y READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Mi código para crear la base de datos es el siguiente:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:dacappo/db/tables.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class DataBase {
  String name = "dacappo";
  int version = 1;

  Future<Database> open() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, name);
    print("Database Path: $path");
    return openDatabase(
      path,
      version: version,
      onConfigure: onConfigure,
      onCreate: onCreate,
    );
  }

  // Resto del código para la creación y configuración de la base de datos...
}
```

A pesar de haber seguido todas las recomendaciones y añadir los permisos necesarios, la base de datos no se crea en dispositivos Android y no puedo almacenar datos.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme a identificar cuál puede ser el problema o qué paso me estoy saltando? Agradezco cualquier sugerencia o solución que puedan brindarme.

¡Gracias por su tiempo y ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que aunque hayas definido en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` los permisos, pero **es necesario que la petición del permiso `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` sea manual**, no necesitas requerir `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`:

```
import 'package:simple_permissions/simple_permissions.dart';

PermissionStatus permissionResult = await SimplePermissions.requestPermission(Permission.WriteExternalStorage);
if (permissionResult == PermissionStatus.authorized){
    //* Aquí se confirma que se tiene el permiso WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE  aceptado.
}
```